# What is standard process of Magento 2 Print Invoice PDF

Tags: magento2

I have a question regarding PDF invoice which can be easily print from Admin. What is the purpose of this print invoice. As when Magento send invoice email it does not send the PDF invoice as downloadable in it.?

Answer (score 0):

They are just 2 different features. Printing an invoice on the admin side just allow the admin to access it while sending threw an email allow the customer to access it.

You also may want to print different kind of data if you send to the customer or if it's for the admin.

I'm not running any market but I guess it's important for sellers to keeps tracks of the invoices for comptability and not just sending them to customers.